# An application that randomly picks images

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an application that randomly picks from a bunch of different images and displays it. I've created this code so far, and while it works there are clearly flaws, like the amount of processing power it takes, and all the lines of code. Is there a way to simplify this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Generation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int number;
    public GameObject img1;
    public GameObject img2;
    public GameObject img3;
    public GameObject img4;
    public GameObject img5;
    public GameObject img6;
    public GameObject img7;
    public GameObject img8;
    public GameObject img9;
    public GameObject img10;
    public GameObject img11;
    public GameObject img12;
    public GameObject img13;
    public GameObject img14;
    public GameObject img15;
    public GameObject img16;
    public GameObject img17;
    public GameObject img18;
    public GameObject img19;
    public GameObject img20;
    public GameObject img21;
    public GameObject img22;
    public GameObject img23;
    public GameObject img24;
    public GameObject img25;
    public GameObject img26;
    public GameObject img27;
    public GameObject img28;
    public GameObject img29;
    public GameObject img30;
    public GameObject img31;
    public GameObject img32;
    public GameObject img33;
    public GameObject img34;
    public GameObject img35;
    public GameObject img36;
    public GameObject img37;
    public GameObject img38;
    public GameObject img39;
    public GameObject img40;
    public GameObject img41;
    public GameObject img42;
    public GameObject img43;
    public GameObject img44;
    public GameObject img45;
    public GameObject img46;
    public GameObject img47;
    public GameObject img48;
    public GameObject img49;
    public GameObject img50;
    public GameObject img51;
    public GameObject img52;
    public GameObject img53;
    public GameObject img54;
    public GameObject img55;
    public GameObject img56;
    public GameObject img57;
    public GameObject img58;
    public GameObject img59;
    public GameObject img60;
    public GameObject img61;
    public GameObject img62;
    public GameObject img63;
    public GameObject img64;
    public GameObject img65;
    public GameObject img66;
    public GameObject img67;
    public GameObject img68;
    public GameObject img69;
    public GameObject img70;
    public GameObject img71;
    public GameObject img72;

    public void ResetScreen()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <transform.childCount; a++)
        {
            transform.GetChild(a).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void RandomGenerate()
    {
        number = Random.Range(1, 73);
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                img1.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                img2.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                img3.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 4:
                img4.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 5:
                img5.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 6:
                img6.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 7:
                img7.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 8:
                img8.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 9:
                img9.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 10:
                img10.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 11:
                img11.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 12:
                img12.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 13:
                img13.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 14:
                img14.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 15:
                img15.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 16:
                img16.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 17:
                img17.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 18:
                img18.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 19:
                img19.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 20:
                img20.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 21:
                img21.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 22:
                img22.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 23:
                img23.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 24:
                img24.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 25:
                img25.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 26:
                img26.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 27:
                img27.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 28:
                img28.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 29:
                img29.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 30:
                img30.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 31:
                img31.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 32:
                img32.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 33:
                img33.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 34:
                img34.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 35:
                img35.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 36:
                img36.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 37:
                img37.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 38:
                img38.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 39:
                img39.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 40:
                img40.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 41:
                img41.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 42:
                img42.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 43:
                img43.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 44:
                img44.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 45:
                img45.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 46:
                img46.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 47:
                img47.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 48:
                img48.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 49:
                img49.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 50:
                img50.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 51:
                img51.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 52:
                img52.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 53:
                img53.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 54:
                img54.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 55:
                img55.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 56:
                img56.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 57:
                img57.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 58:
                img58.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 59:
                img59.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 60:
                img60.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 61:
                img61.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 62:
                img62.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 63:
                img63.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 64:
                img64.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 65:
                img65.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 66:
                img66.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 67:
                img67.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 68:
                img68.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 69:
                img69.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 70:
                img70.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 71:
                img71.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 72:
                img72.SetActive(true);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array, then pick a random number int wise, between 0 and length of array?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it like this:

```cs
public GameObject[] imgs = new GameObject[72]; // This is an array of 72 GameObjects
public void RandomGenerate() {
    imgs[Random.Range(0,72) /* indexing starts from 0 */].SetActive(true);
}
```

Read about C# arrays [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).

Answer (score 1):

Theres 2 options:

Unless you need to access each of those gameobjects from somewhere else you should consider using [SerializeField] rather than public - minimal access, etc.

so

```
[SerializeField] GameObject imgs; // unity now warns about this, its safe to ignore. I often set things to null just to shut it up
   public void ResetScreen()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <transform.childCount; a++)
        {
            transform.GetChild(a).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void RandomGenerate()
    {
// if you supply random range with ints, it picks ints, between first and 1 less than last which is what you wanted.
        if (imgs.Length>0)
           imgs[Random.Range(0, imgs.Length)].SetActive(true); 

    }
```

However, your resetScreen code, got me thinking, they are all subparts of the current object right? in which case if the imgs are the ONLY sub parts of this you could do even less, but only if they are the only bits..

and just have.. no arrays at all because unity already has it

```
   public void ResetScreen()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <transform.childCount; a++)
        {
            transform.GetChild(a).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void RandomGenerate()
    {
// if you supply random range with ints, it picks ints, between first and 1 less than last which is what you wanted.
        if (transform.childCount>0)
           transform.GetChild(Random.Range(0, transform.childCount)).gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
```